# I am trying to get from my User: first_name and last_name, and noting is hapening in my html code

Tags: python, html, django, django-models, django-templates

**This is my model.py, you can see that I add field postUser, from User in ForingeKey:**

```
class Post(models.Model):
    postUser = models.ForeignKey(User,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    task_title = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    task_discription = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    task_category = models.ForeignKey(TaskCategory, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    recommended_tools = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    budget = models.IntegerField(default=0)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.postUser) + ' | ' +self.task_title + ' | ' + self.task_discription + ' | ' + str(self.task_category) + ' | ' + self.recommended_tools + ' | ' + str(self.budget) + ' | ' + str(self.id)

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('post_detail', args=[str(self.id)])
```

**After this I create a view in view.py:**

```
class PostDetail(DetailView):                                 
    model = Post
    template_name = 'post_detail.html'
```

**And finally my post detail page in HTML file:**

```
{% extends "nav_footer.html" %}
{% load static %}
{% block content %}

<section class="section gray-bg" id="blog">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row justify-content-center ">
        <div class="col-sm-4">
            <div class="blog-grid">
              <div class="blog-info">
                <h3 class="text-center"> Job title:</h3>
                <p class="text-center">{{ post.task_title }}</p>
                <h3 class="text-center"> Author:</h3>
                <p class="text-center">{{ post.postUser }}</p>
                <h3 class="text-center"> Author:</h3>
                <p class="text-center">{{ post.postUser.first_name }}</p>
              </div>
             </div>
            </div>
          </div>
         </div>
      </section>
   {% endblock %}
```

**Noting seems to show up in p class="text-center"{{ post.postUser.first_name }}p?**

Comment: Are you sure that user has a `first_name`? By default the `first_name` is empty.

Comment: I just deleted migrations and makemigrations again , and now it is working fine

Answer (score 0):

1. Did you add your Configuration into your installed apps within settings.py? it should be something like name.apps.nameConfig
2. Make sure all syntax is correct, for example, I often forget little commas in settings.py which messes everything up
3. You need to make migrations in your command prompt by first using `python manage.py makemigrations polls` and then `python manage.py sqlmigrate polls 0001`
4. Follow this tutorial [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/intro/tutorial02/) closely, it has everything you need for models and migrations.

I really hope this helps you, I am very new to Stack Overflow and just want to help!